# Saving values of variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, variables

Hi for my code I would like to know how to best save my variable `column`. `column` is 733x1. Ideally I would like to have 
`column1(y)=column`, but I obtain the error:

> Conversion to cell from logical is not possible.

in the inner loop. I find it difficult to access these stored values in `overlap`.

```
for i = 1:7 
    for y = 1:ydim % ydim = 436
        %execute code  %code produces different 'column' on each iteration 
        column1{y} = column; %'column' size 733x1 %altogether 436 sets of 'column'
    end
    overlap{i} = column1; %iterates 7 times. 
end
```

Ideally I want `overlap` to store 7 variables saved that are (733x436).
Thanks.

Comment: To rephrase your question, you are asking, ***how to access the stored values in `overlap`***, is that what you are asking?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using cell arrays rather than concatenating your column vectors into a 2d array? It appears that they're all the same size.

Comment: There are numerous conversion from cells to matrices in MATLAB. Since we do not know the size of  `column_fill` or how it relatese to `column1` it is hard to say though. But maybe this is not the problem? I just assumed this since you provided an error message.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that mistake in my post. Now updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `column` is calculated using a procedure where each column is dependent on the latter. If not, then there are very likely improvements that can be made to this:

```
column = zeros(733, 1);           % Might not need this. Depends on you code.
all_columns = zeros(xdim, ydim);  % Pre-allocate memory (always do this)
                                  % Note that the first dimension is usually called x,
                                  % and the second called y in MATLAB
overlap = cell(7, 1);
overlap(:) = {zeros(xdim, ydim)}; % Pre-allocate memory

for ii = 1:numel(overlap)         % numel is better than length
    for jj = 1:ydim               % ii and jj are better than i and j
        % several_lines_of_code_to_calculate_column
        column = something;
        all_columns(:, jj) = column;
    end
    overlap{ii} = all_columns;
end
```

You can access the variables in `overlap` like this: `overlap{1}(1,1);`. This will get the first element in the first cell. `overlap{2}` will get the entire matrix in the second cell.

You specified that you wanted 7 variables. Your code implies that you know that cells are better than assigning it to different variables (`var1`, `var2` ...). Good! The solution with different variables is bad bad bad.

Instead of using a cell array, you could instead use a 3D-array. This might make processing later on faster, if you can vectorize stuff for instance.

This will be:

```
column = zeros(733, 1);        % Might not need this. Depends on you code.
overlap = zeros(xdim, ydim, 7) % Pre-allocate memory for 3D-matrix

for ii = 1:7
   for jj = 1:ydim
      % several_lines_of_code_to_calculate_column
      column = something;
      all_column(:, jj, ii) = column;
    end
end
```